# How to achieve the lowest possible level of access to keys?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AHK for a while and I love it! But today I noticed something weird.

I tend to use scripts to automate things like task switching, audio mute/unmute on applications, etc.
I started playing the game Call of Duty: Black Ops 4 and my hotkeys were acting weird. They did what they should, but with a few "extra" actions I didn't want. The problem was, that AHK couldn't block access to any keys which was bound to an action in the settings of the game.

Step by step I tried to fix this and narrow down what the specific problem could be. I tried things like:

```
F1::
  Send, f
Return

F1::Return

VK70::Return

SC03B::Return
```

None of these worked. Yes, the first one wrote the character "f" when the chat was open, but all of them did the action what it should for the game.

And another example of this control of the game is the Caps Lock key, which can't be used in some situations, because it toggles the Map in-game. And to prevent confusion when using the chat, the developers disabled it when it can be used as a map toggle. Because of this, I can't bind any AHK hotkey to Caps Lock, because it won't fire when it is blocked by the game.

I'd like to ask if I could "catch" these keys earlier somehow, before it reaches the applications? How could I implement my script lower, than it is by default?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running your script as an administrator?

Comment: Keyboard events are generally handled in the reverse order they were added. Sometimes, you can get beat an application using contextual hotkeys (i.e. "if window is COD" do "x") (see https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context), and other times you need to manually register keyboard hooks using the `SetWindowsHookEx` windows API (see https://github.com/PProvost/AutoHotKey/blob/master/DisableTouchPad.ahk).

In the latter case, if it doesn't work to start with, try detecting COD starting, wait 10 seconds, then inject a manual keyboard hook.

Disclaimer: Beware of anti-cheat software.

Answer (score 1):

My [AutoHotInterception](https://github.com/evilC/AutoHotInterception) library uses a custom device driver and allows you to block below the OS layer. You want the "Subscription Mode" method, not the "Context mode" method.